# How can I solve this path error in project 'not a valid python path'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, path

Hi guys I tried recently to create a new django project. So I run 'pipenv install django'. And this was the error I had.

```
  File "C:\Users\KONLAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "C:\Users\KONLAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 624, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/KONLAN/Downloads/Anaconda/python.exe'
```

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS?

Answer (score 0):

you can use package manager pip:

```py
pip install django
```

or

```py
pip3 install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems have been solved in [GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4334), and solutions have also been given:

Search for **`Python351`** in regedit (win+r , regedit) and delete the entries.